# Make multiple calls in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have some mock data for below 2 URLS:

```
1. Get the list of users from 'https://myapp.com/authors'.
2. Get the list of Books from 'https://myapp.com/books'.
```

Now my task is to sort the Books by name and write the sorted list to the file `mysortedbooks.json` as JSON

Then I have to create an array of authors with books property that has all the books of that author.

If the author has no books then this array should be empty. Sorting is not needed for this case, and data should be stored in file `authorBooks.json` as JSON.

Now I have to return a promise that resolves when the above steps are complete. For example, I should return the final `saveToFile` call in below code.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function getFromURL(url) {
    switch (url) {
        case 'https://myapp.com/authors':
            return Promise.resolve([
                { name: "Chinua Achebe", id: "1" },
                { name: "Hans Christian Andersen", id: "2" },
                { name: "Dante Alighieri", id: "3" },
            ]);
        case 'https://myapp.com/books':
            return Promise.resolve([
                { name: "Things Fall Apart", authorId: "1" },
                { name: "The Epic Of Gilgamesh", authorId: "1" },
                { name: "Fairy tales", authorId: "2" },
                { name: "The Divine Comedy", authorId: "2" },
                { name: "One Thousand and One Nights", authorId: "1" },
                { name: "Pride and Prejudice", authorId: "2" },
            ]);
    }
}

const outFile = fs.createWriteStream('...out-put-path...');

function saveToFile(fileName, data) {
    outFile.write(`${fileName}: ${data}\n`);

    return Promise.resolve();
}


function processData() {
    const authors = getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors').then(author => {
        return authors;
    });

    const books = getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors').then(books => {
        return books.sort();
    });

    return saveToFile('mysortedbooks.json', JSON.stringify(books)).then(() => {
        const authorAndBooks = authors.map(author => {
            var jsonData = {};
            jsonData['name'] = author.name;
            jsonData['books'] = [];
            for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
                if(authod.id == books[i].authorId) {
                    jsonData['books'].push(books[i].name);
                }
            }
        });

        saveToFile('authorBooks.json', authorAndBooks);
    });
}

processData().then(() => outFile.end());
```

The main logic I have to implement is in `processData` method.

I tried adding code to solve the requirement but I got stuck how to return `promise` after all the operations. Also how to build my `authorAndBooks` JSON content.

Please help me with this.

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? You can refactor your code to use async-await rather than promises to make it easier to understand.

Comment: (although it's good practice to try to fully understand promises)

Comment: `output-file` is an invalid variable name

Comment: @TKoL, sorry small type. I have changed it to `outFile`.

Comment: There's several problems with the code. For example since `const authors` is a resolved promise, code like `authors.map()` should throw an error, since it should be `authors.then( authors => authors.map());`. Also no idea why you prefer to use streams when you can just overwrite the entire json file.

Comment: @Shilly, I was given a template and change it as per given requirement, so I was using the template to perform this task.

Answer (score 6):

```
const authors = getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors').then(author => {
    return authors;
});

const books = getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors').then(books => {
    return books.sort();
});

//authors and books are both promises here, so await them
return Promise.all([authors, books]).then(function(results){
    authors = results[0];
    books = results[1];
    return saveToFile(...);
});
```

alternatively declare your function async and do

```
const authors = await getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors').then(author => {
    return authors;
});

const books = await getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors').then(books => {
    return books.sort();
});

return await saveToFile(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, is my variable `authorAndBooks` is properly built in my code, can you please check.

Comment: afaik, Promise.join() requires bluebird. Did you mean `Promise.all()`?

Comment: `Promise.all([ authors, books ]).then()`. don't forget the array. And for the async version, you don't have to actually chain the .then() to return the value. that's exactly what `await` is supposed to do. Sorry for coming across nitpickery. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: The `.then`s in your async version are unnecessary; that's why `await` is great!

Answer (score 0):

Refactored code with Promise Chaining and to create multiple file streams

```
const fs = require('fs');

function getFromURL(url) {
    switch (url) {
        case 'https://myapp.com/authors':
            return Promise.resolve([
                { name: "Chinua Achebe", id: "1" },
                { name: "Hans Christian Andersen", id: "2" },
                { name: "Dante Alighieri", id: "3" },
            ]);
        case 'https://myapp.com/books':
            return Promise.resolve([
                { name: "Things Fall Apart", authorId: "1" },
                { name: "The Epic Of Gilgamesh", authorId: "1" },
                { name: "Fairy tales", authorId: "2" },
                { name: "The Divine Comedy", authorId: "2" },
                { name: "One Thousand and One Nights", authorId: "1" },
                { name: "Pride and Prejudice", authorId: "2" },
            ]);
    }
}

function saveToFile(fileName, data) {
    const outFile = fs.createWriteStream(`/var/${fileName}`);
    outFile.write(data);
    return Promise.resolve(outFile);
}

function authorBookMapping(data) {
    let [authors, books] = data;
    var jsonData = {};            
    authors.map(author => {
        jsonData['name'] = author.name;
        jsonData['books'] = [];
        for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
            if(author.id == books[i].authorId) {
                jsonData['books'].push(books[i].name);
            }
        }
    });
    return {
        books: books,
        authorAndBooks: jsonData
    };  
}

function writeFile(data) {
    if(data) {
        const {books, authorAndBooks} = data;
        const book = saveToFile('mysortedbooks.json', JSON.stringify(books));
        const author = saveToFile('authorBooks.json', JSON.stringify(authorAndBooks));
        return Promise.all([book, author]);
    }    
}


function processData() {            

        const authors = getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors');

        const books = getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors');

        return Promise.all([authors, books])
                .then(authorBookMapping)
                .then(writeFile)                
}

processData().then((stream) => {
    for(let s in stream) {
        stream[s].close();
    }
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log("Err :", err);
}) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

lot of mistakes in your code. I will try to explain one by one, read comments between code. I would recommend you to read some basics of file operations and promises. Problem is in your saveToFile method and how you are chaining promises in processData method.

Change your saveToFIle function as following. You can also use promise supporting fs libraries like fs-extra but I'm not sure if you want to use an external library.

```
const path = require('path');     
const basePath = '.';//whatever base path of your directories    
function saveToFile(fileName, data) {
// fs.writeFile method uses callback, you can use many ways to convert a callback method to support promises
// this is one of the simple and doesn't require any libraries to import
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let filePath = path.join(basePath,fileName);
        return fs.writeFile(filePath,data,(err, data)=>{
            if(err) reject(err);
          else resolve();
        });
    })
}
```

Now change your processData function to use promise.all and to sort boooks in right way

```
function processData() {
    let books, authors;
    //Promise.all can be used when operations are not interdependent, fteches result fasetr as works like parallel requests
    return Promise.all([
        getFromURL('https://myapp.com/books'),
        getFromURL('https://myapp.com/authors')
    ]).then(data => {
        books = data[0];
        authors = data[1];
        let authorAndBooks = authors.map(author => {
            let jsonData = {};
            jsonData['name'] = author.name;
            jsonData['books'] = [];
            for(var i=0; i<books.length; i++) {
                if(author.id == books[i].authorId) {
                    jsonData['books'].push(books[i].name);
                }
            }
            return jsonData;
            console.log(jsonData);
        });
         // you will have to use a comparator to sort objects, given below it will sort books based on names.
         books.sort((first,second)=>{ return first.name>second.name ?1:-1})
        return Promise.all([
        saveToFile("mysortedbooks.json",JSON.stringify(books)),
        saveToFile("authorBooks.json",JSON.stringify(authorAndBooks))])
    }).then(data=>{
        console.log('All operations complete');
    }) 
}

processData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking at this in a different way? If this is going to be the case for other APIs I'd think about aggregating those APIs in an aggregator service or the API itself if you can.

It is always better to receive all the data you need at once rather than multiple calls, you will incur latency and complexity.